# Screen lock photos but without login

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 offers beautiful lock screen photos before showing the logon box.  I have already disabled the required login feature, but still would like to see those beautiful photos.
How can I make Windows 10 randomly show these lock screen photos as backgrounds for the Windows desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The default setting of background to Windows 10 lock screen interface is "Windows spotlight", then the lock screen interface will randomly change the wallpaper according to Windows push.

1.Check the two options in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WSVi.jpg).

2.Search for a folder named "Assets" in the C drive, there may be a lot of eligible folders. Be careful to match the circled folder in the [image](https://imgur.com/a/THHx2Yq).

3.Open this folder and select the files that take up a bit more space and add .jpg or .png at the end of the file name. Then open the files and you will find that they are the interfaces when the screen is locked. As shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UloAb.jpg).

4.Copy these beautiful photos into a new folder and I will name it "test". Then in the "personalize" settings:

Background->Slideshow; Choose albums for your slideshow->test; Change picture every->as you like

As shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDZ38.jpg).

Indeed, it's too trouble. And sometimes the quality of the displayed image is very poor.

**I prefer to recommend that you use some third-party tools related to wallpaper to provide you with beautiful wallpapers.**